# Batch copy script with user prompting

Tags: batch-file, input, prompt, xcopy

If I following syntax, everything works.

```
xcopy source destination /e
```

but when I want to make it a script in next fashion:

```
set /p src = Enter source directory: 
set /p dest = Enter destination directory: 

xcopy "%src%" "%dest%" /e

pause
```

then it doesn't work. It gives me Invalid drive specification. %src% and %dest% are usually c:/somedirectory

Answer (score 1):

`%src%` and `%dest%` are not defined.
What you *have* defined, is `%src %` and `%dest %`.
Batch is a bit picky with usage of spaces. Correct is:

```
set /p "src=Enter source directory: "
set /p "dest=Enter destination directory: "

xcopy "%src%" "%dest%" /e

pause
```

Note the missing spaces around the `=` and the quotes and their position.
(the quotes are not really neccessary, but they help to define exactly where your string ends and avoids problems with some special characters)

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I will be more alert next time. I have been trying this for couple of hours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine without blanks after the variable:

```
set /p src=Enter source directory: 
set /p dest=Enter destination directory: 
xcopy "%src%" "%dest%" /e

pause
```